# Ruby testing: printing inside a test case

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

I'm brand new to Ruby testing and Google isn't helping.

Using Test/Unit, how can I print an instance variable, like

```
test "thing to happen" do
  do_stuff
  assert_equal "foo", @variable
  p @varible
end
```

Comment: That code should output @variable to the console, except when the assert fails. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: is the instance variable in the test case or in the object under test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby [asserts](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Unit_testing#Available_Assertions) can output messages to test runner console:

```
test "thing to happen" do
  do_stuff
  assert_equal "foo", @variable, "@variable is #{@variable} when: things to happen"
  p @varible
end
```